# Do we assume a value to be true be considered as 1 in algebraic manipulation?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In my Digital Logics class, we are doing boolean algebra.

In the case where $ a * b * c $ (a and b and c)
can we assume either of those values to be 1?
so can we say that $a * b * c = 1 * b * c$,
in which case that would be $(a + a') * b * c$?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. The question doesn't make sense in a vacuum. You're free to assume whatever you want, if that's the situation you mean to consider.

Comment: I'm given a function of a, b, c, and minterms 1, 3, 4, 6, 7. and... I'm not sure how to ask this  question, but I just went over the problem with assuming that...

Comment: I don't know what minterms are, but if you have more details you should edit them into the question. More detail is generally better.